# Magento prevent duplicate product & category url's

Tags: magento, url, duplicates

How can the admin user be informed when he create a product or category that the url key already exist with an error message and block the product/category creation until he change the product/category name or url key?

Thanks.

Comment: ..talking about Magento 1.x

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a solution for this issue. I will post here a summary answer, if somebody have some questions, please ask.

**Category**: create an observer and for 'catalog_category_save_before' event add a url check validation, can be done with direct sql, something like:

```
  $query = " SELECT value_id
    FROM catalog_category_entity_varchar
    WHERE value = '" . $urlKey . "' AND attribute_id = (
        SELECT attribute_id
        FROM eav_attribute
        WHERE entity_type_id = 3 AND attribute_code = 'url_key')
    ";
```

**Products**: 2 things here...one to check the url when it's created from product name (if url key is empty on save product) and another one if url key is specified on product save:

- add a backend model for the product 'name' attribute and on validate() method check for duplicate value if url key is not set, something like:

  ```
  $urlKey = $object->getData('url_key');
  if ($urlKey) {
      return true;
  }

  if (!$this->getAttribute()->getEntity()->checkAttributeUniqueValue($this->getAttribute(), $object)) {
      throw Mage::exception('Mage_Eav',
          Mage::helper('eav')->__('The value of this attribute must be unique if you do not set explicit URL Key')
      );
  }
  ```
- ovewrite in config.xml the urlkey backend model and the same like for 'name' attribute, add under validate() method the duplicate check, like:

  ```
  if (!$this->getAttribute()->getEntity()->checkAttributeUniqueValue($this->getAttribute(), $object)) {
      $label = $this->getAttribute()->getFrontend()->getLabel();
      throw Mage::exception('Mage_Eav',
          Mage::helper('eav')->__('The value of attribute "%s" must be unique', $label)
      );
  }
  ```